# javascript tabs nav change content

Tags: javascript

I'm making javascript tabs navigation. And don't know what is the best way to change content. Have some variants : show/hide elements, change innerHTML of content, XMLhttpRequest (but this is only server technology, as I know, and cant get data of local files, is this true?). Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to have content pre-loaded and hidden (unless it is huge) in order for it to be indexed by search engines and to reduce the amount of time the user has to wait. Changing the visibility of what's there is by far the easiest method.